# How can I force my Mac Mini to eject a DVD

Tags: macos, dvd, mac-mini, eject

Today I put a movie DVD into my Mac Mini, but the Finder doesn't show it => the Mac doesn't seem to know it is there.

How can I force an eject?

Note: Booting with all kinds of keys CMD, ALT, Apple or Mouse pressed didn't help either (found that on the net).

ONE MONTH LATER

Today I tried to install Snow Leopard on my Mac Mini.

I inserted the DVD, answered lot's of questions, then, when I expected it to copy files, it gave me the beach ball.

Two hours and a boot later, I noticed that once again the DVD was not recognized/detected in the drive and could not be ejected until I nudged it with my pen knife...

I guess I'll be upgrading some other way ... (the mini is by now solidly out of warranty)

Comment: Booting with the mouse button pressed should always work. Sounds like something is quite broken.

Comment: Unless still under warranty, when all else fails...go for the screwdriver.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are a few methods depending on how "stuck" it is:

**Method 1 :**
Use Disk Utility to eject The first
    and simplest method, if you only
    want to unmount a single volume on
    the disk, is to use Disk Utility,
    located in Applications/Utilities.
    In Disk Utility, simply select the
    volume you want to unmount and click
    Eject.

**Method 2 :**
Hold Down the mouse button at
    startup In some cases holding down a
    connected mouse button at startup
    will cause a misbehaving optical
    drive to eject its media.

**Method 3:** 
    Boot into Open Firmware and eject If
    you have a Mac that will not startup
    properly and has a stuck disc, try
    booting into Open Firmware by
    holding down Command, Option, O key
    and F key during startup. After
    booting into Open Firmware, type the
    command eject-cd.

**Method 4:**
Using the Terminal. There are two commands that can be used in the Terminal (located in Applications/Utilities) which can be used to force disk ejection:

```
drutil tray eject.
```

Simply type in the above command and press return.

Last resort method (Danger, Will Robinson!):

Also knwon as, *Ye olde screwdriver method*.

1. Turn the CPU upside down and lay it
   flat on a desk or table. Use a
   flat-edged knife or small pry bar to
   gently and carefully lift the bottom
   panel off the unit.
2. Use a small Phillips-head
   screwdriver to remove the four
   screws at the corners of the large,
   flat, shiny metal panel directly
   below the bottom panel. Lift off the
   panel to expose the CD drive and
   remove the CD carefully with your
   fingers.
3. Replace the metal panel and its
   screws, then snap the bottom cover
   back into place. Reattach all of the
   cables and boot up the computer.

If you still can't it out using the last method, then you a really, ahem, stuck. 
Call the fruit company.

;-)

Comment: thanx for the comprehensive answer ..  I tried (and retried, what I'd attempted before) all your suggestions (except the old english one) ... what helped was the word **"stuck"**. Using a swiss army knife (I own the original) and a flashlight, I gently nudged the disk in the drive ... then rebooted while pressing the mouse button => one freed DVD! **THANK YOU**

Comment: Your welcome. Btw, MacGyver would be proud with what you did with your knife. ;-)

Comment: There is one more method (that wouldn't have worked for me, but might help someone else), I read in a TUAW article. An eject button can be placed on the menu bar:  http://www.tuaw.com/2009/11/02/mac-101-how-to-manually-enable-menu-extras/

Comment: Method 4 seems simplest and most reliable

Comment: about Method 2, note that even in the case of wire mouse, I have tested some mouse can not work, so try with other if doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The usual advice is to try the `f12` key. And you can find install a menu item to do this by double clicking on `System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Eject.menu`.

Comment: the machine does not see the disk ..

Answer (score 0):

### **ONE MONTH LATER**

Today I tried to install Snow Leopard on my Mac Mini.

I inserted the DVD, answered lot's of questions, then, when I expected it to copy files, it gave me the beach ball.

Two hours and a boot later, I noticed that once again the DVD was not recognized/detected in the drive and could not be ejected until I nudged it with my pen knife...

I guess I'll be upgrading some other way ... (the mini is by now solidliy out of warranty)